# elementary abelian subgroup of finite non-cyclic $p$-group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups

Let $G$ be a finite non-cyclic $p$-group of order $p^n$, $n >1$, where $p$ is odd prime. I need to prove(By elementary methods)that $G$ has a subgroup isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}_p \times \Bbb{Z}_p$?

Comment: This is not true unless you also assume that $p > 2$.

Comment: why? i think it is correct

Comment: Then you should look at some examples of $2$-groups.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Also I think it is correct for *any* prime $\;p\;$. Do you have some counter example in mind?

Comment: @DonAntonio All the generalized quaternion groups (these are in fact precisely the counter examples).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Of course, you're right. I could have sworn the question was about *abelian* groups. All the proper subgroups of $\;\mathcal Q_8\;$ are cyclic...and normal, btw. Thanks.\

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft thanks, i editet  question

Comment: Hmm, not sure about an elementary proof. Normally, I would note that by induction one can assume that the group has a cyclic subgroup of index $p$ and use the classification of these.

Comment: since $G$ is non-cyclic, it has at least two maximal subgroups. induction on what?

Comment: Induction on the size of the group (i.e. consider a minimal counter example).

Comment: I don't get it, $|G|=p^n$ so $o(g) \ |\ p^n$ and $o(g^a) = p$ for some $a$, and taking a $h \ne 1$, $\  \langle h \rangle \ \cap \ \langle g^a \rangle = \ \{1\}$ should do the trick : $o(h^b) = p$ and  $\langle g^a,h^b \rangle \simeq \mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_p $ ?

Comment: Thanks, if i cant use of the classificatin, then i can prove question?

Comment: Sure, the classification says that up to isomorphism there is a unique non-abelian group of order $p^n$ with a cyclic subgroup of index $p$ (when $p$ is odd). And it is easy to check that this group has plenty of subgroup of order $p$.

Comment: @user1952009 That will not work as it does not account for those cases where the result is not true.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft that's why I said "I don't get it". Can you explain the problem with my algorithm ? (once you have $o(g^a) = p$, there exists a $h \ne 1, \langle g^a \rangle \cap \langle h \rangle = \{1\}$ since otherwise $G$ is cyclic)

Comment: @user1952009 Well, that last claim is not true.

Comment: @user1952009 extraspecial groups satisfy all those conditions, except they are not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_p\times \mathbb{Z}_p$. For example, $D_8$ is generated by 2 reflections of the square.

Answer (score 0):

If $G$ is abelian, then $G$ has at least two distinct subgroups of order $p$ such as $H,K$. Thus $H \times K \cong \Bbb{Z}_p \times \Bbb{Z}_p $.

Now let $G$ is non-abelian. We use induction on $n$. If all maximal subgroups of $G$ are cyclic, then $G \cong Q_8$, a contradiction. Thus there exists a non-cyclic maximal subgroup of $G$ such as $H$. By induction hypothesis $H$ has a non-cyclic subgroup of order $p^2$. Thus $G$ has a non-cyclic subgroup of order $p^2$.

Comment: Under what assumption on an abelian group $G$ are you assuming it has at least two distinct subgroups of order $p$?

Comment: @Nex Because if $G$ is a finite abelian $p$-group such that $G$ has exactly one subgroup of order $p$, then $G$ is cyclic.